# pending intent not working in notification created by a service

Tags: android, service, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have two activities A and B. A is launched when the application is started. I have a service  which is launched from A.

here's my code in Activity A.

```
Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Service_class.class));

        }
    });
```

Here's the onStartCommand method in my service.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    createNotification();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

here's the createNotification method

```
private void createNotification() {

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent nintent = new Intent();
    nintent.setClass(this, TestActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pin = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            0, nintent, 0);
    String title = "KR Darsan";
    String body = "This is a notification from darsh";
    Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, body,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    n.contentIntent = pin;
    n.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), title, body, pin);

    n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    nm.notify(unique_id, n);

}
```

I am setting the Activity B  (TestActivity) in the pending intent. Notification shows up as I need but when I click on the notification, the activity is not launched.

I declared the service in the manifest.

```
<service android:name=".Service_class" />
```

Is there something else I should declare in the manifest ? What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you declared `TestActivity.class` in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: My bad! Thanks for pointing out. I make silly mistakes all the time.

Comment: Are you saying that TestActivity.class should be listed in BOTH manifests?  I.e., in both Activity A's and Activity B's manifest?

Comment: Activity is one single window of an app, not the app itself. The app or library project can have only one manifest.